# HTML/CSS: navigation with horizontal submenu without overlapping element below

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}
nav {
  font-size: 85%;
  line-height: 2;
}
nav ul {
  background-color: #222;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}
nav a {
  background-color: #222;
  font-size: 120%;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:link,
nav a:visited {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 3% 2px 0;
}
nav a:hover,
nav a:active,
nav .active a:link,
nav .active a:visited {
  color: #3d99ed;
  text-shadow: none;
}
nav a.selected {
  color: #3d99ed;
}
nav ul li div {
  background-color: #444;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul li ul {
  background-color: #444;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 1170px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 89%;
}
nav ul li ul li {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 1180px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 90%;
}
nav ul li ul li a {
  background-color: #444;
  font-size: 120%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 600px) {
  nav {
    height: 160px;
  }
  nav a:hover,
  nav a:active,
  nav .active a:link,
  nav .active a:visited {
    background-color: #3d99ed;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: none;
  }
  nav ul {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  nav ul li {
    font-size: 140%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    background-color: #444;
    margin: 3px;
  }
  nav a:link,
  nav a:visited {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="/">Item1</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Item2</a>

      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">SubItem2A</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">SubItem2B</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Item3</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Item4</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<h1>This Title is not fully visible</h1>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/">Item1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<h1>This Title is visible</h1>
```

I'm trying to implement a navigation containing a submenu. From a semantic point of view I thought it would be best to wrap the submenu with the top menu item which it belongs to.

I tried to post only the relevant part of it

The thing is, in order to display the submenu bellow the main navigation, I had to set the position `absolute` (see the `nav ul li div` rule). This causes the navigation to overlap the content below. How can I prevent this?

I also made a fiddle with more complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/xxs7fjt9/1/
It also contains a responsive part, where the overlap also occurs, of course.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question? Why are you using `position:absolute` if you don't want the content to overlap?

Comment: This isn't a full answer, but the partially obscured header can be fixed with position:relative - http://jsfiddle.net/xxs7fjt9/3/

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

If you don't want it to be dependend on hover (= always show the submenu), and let other elements respect your submenu, you have to make the 'nav' and 'h1' float left and give them a width of 100%.
To test this you can remove the submenu and you will see that the title will always have the same offset in regards to the menu.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s08j9od8/2/

```
h1 {
    float: left;
    width:100%;
}
nav {
    font-size: 85%;
    line-height: 2;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Old answer:

It is normal for a submenu to overlap lower contents, this is generally acceptable semantics.

If you don't want this, then your best option would be to make the submenu relative positioned. Then on hover of parent menu, show the submenu, this would then cause the title below it to drop the same distance as the submenu.

I made a fiddle with a working example, and also solved the responsive version (the titles were overlapping the mobile menu)

http://jsfiddle.net/s08j9od8/

The code:

```
nav ul li div {
    display:none;
    background-color: #444;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

The hover:

```
    nav ul li:hover div {
    display:block;
    float: left;
}
```

Also I had to remove this in your media query, to solve the overlapping titles on small screens:

```
nav {
    height: 160px;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but I'm not looking for a :hover approach, since it doesn't meet the requirements I got. However, even the title is visible now, the submenu still overlapps the margin of the <h1>
Or in other words: the distance between navigation and h1 should be the same as the distance between submenu and h1, if a submenu occurs (the submenu won't occur on some pages)

Comment: wow thank you, that actually works! Can you explain me, why I need to set the float left?

Comment: sorry, I implemented it and figured out that it leads to several problems. e.g. when I want to display a table after the h1 element, it will be displayed on the top right side. check my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/717e4p83/4/

Comment: Floats give you a better control over the positioning of elements.
In this case you only need to give your table a float too:
<table style="float: left; width:100%">
See the new fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/717e4p83/5/

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the price of absolute positioning, you'll probably need to adjust your content accordingly by applying the padding-top to your h1, lets say

```
h1 { padding-top:20px }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you
the problem I see here, is, that the submenu will still overlapp the h1, even the h1 will be visible because of the padding. I don't want the submenu to overlap the element bellow. I'm looking for a solution, in which the space which the submenu need will be "respected" by other elements.